# rarfile library installation exception

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7

I installed the rarfile library with Activepython (I'm working on mac os and eclipse) and alhthough everyhting seems to have been correctly installed, I still continue to receive this error message with a simple extract test :

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rarfile.py", line 1843, in custom_popen
    raise RarExecError("Unrar not installed? (rarfile.UNRAR_TOOL=%r)" % UNRAR_TOOL)
rarfile.RarExecError: Unrar not installed? (rarfile.UNRAR_TOOL='unrar')
```

I checked where the rarfile library is installed on my computer and defined the library path in the include files on Eclipse (Window -> Preferences -> Pydev -> Interpreter - Python -> System PYTHONPATH) with these paths :

```
/Bibliothèque/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rarfile-2.6-py2.7.egg-info

/Bibliothèque/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rarfile.py

/Bibliothèque/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rarfile.pyc

/Bibliothèque/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rarfile.pyo
```

I still got this error message :

```
File "/Users/moi/Documents/workspace/Apprentissage/Dezipper/test_rarfile_2.py", line 3, in <module>
    ref.extractall('/Users/moi/Downloads/_zips/rars/')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rarfile.py", line 675, in extractall
    self._extract(fnlist, path, pwd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rarfile.py", line 1202, in _extract
    p = custom_popen(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rarfile.py", line 1843, in custom_popen
    raise RarExecError("Unrar not installed? (rarfile.UNRAR_TOOL=%r)" % UNRAR_TOOL)
rarfile.RarExecError: Unrar not installed? (rarfile.UNRAR_TOOL='unrar')
```

Any idea of the problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem.
In addition to the rarfile library installation in python, I need to install the unrar library as well. On mac os x, this is possible by doing this in the terminal :

```
cd /tmp
curl -o output.tar.gz http://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarosx-3.9.3.tar.gz
Untar the tar ball, enter:

tar -zxvf output.tar.gz
```

Now, rar are extracted and I don't get an error message anymore. Good to know.